# Running Mule Standalone vs Tomcat in Production

Tags: esb, mule, production

There are many ways of deploying Mule ESB into a production environment. According to the documentation, it appears that running Mule as a standalone service is the recommended way of doing so.

Are there any reasons for NOT running Mule standalone in production? I'm sure its stable, but how does it compare to Tomcat as far as performance, reliability, and resource utilization go?

Should I still consider running it within Tomcat for any reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Tomcat, or any other web container, allows you to use the web tier of that container for HTTP inbound endpoint (via the Servlet transport) instead of either Mule's HTTP or Jetty transports.

Other differences are found in class loading, handling of hot redeployment and logging.

Now the main reason why people do not use Mule standalone is corporate policy, ie "thou shalt deploy on **_**". When production teams have gained experience babysitting a particular Java app/web server, they want you to deploy your Mule project in that context so they can administer/monitor it in a well-known and consistent manner.

But if you're happy with the inbound HTTP layer you get in Mule standalone and you are allowed to deploy it in production, then go for it. It's production ready.

Comment: Thanks David! I am actually in the process of reading the MEAP copy of your Mule in Action book. Enjoying it so far!

Comment: Is there anything I should be aware of running standalone? Is it prone to PermGen issues? Should we increase the JVM heap size? Any other gotchyas? I am familiar with these admin issues with Tomcat / Spring. But I have never deployed a stand along mule container.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such problem, except http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699940/gc-too-frequency-under-heavy-load-with-mule3-2 (which will happen with both Mule embedded and standalone). Most of the behavior should be the same as a Spring web-app. Differences will occur in the handling of app hot reloading, which is quite different between TC and Mule Standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Mule actually recommends deploying standalone. Inside a container like e.g. tomcat it has to share the threadpool, heap etc... This can obviously prevent it from performing at it's best.

The main reason you'd want to inside a container like tomcat is to get automatic deployment. I.e. you can just update your Mule application .war and the container will restart mule with the new application. This helps in testing.

Also some transports are specific to running inside a container, like the servlet transport. OTOH when designing solution so Mule transports between your container and your servlets [your'e doing it wrong.](http://funny-pictures.funmunch.com/funny-picture-485.html)